# Cypher query for nested relationships (map like query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find out if there is a Cypher query to perform map like query functions. Given the example data.

```
                        (stack)
                      /    |   \
                     /     |    \
                (item)  (item)  (item)
                 /  \      |       / \
                /    \     |      /   \
           (node) (node) (node) (node)(node)
```

Thus far the query I have for matching the `node`s  is.

```
START stack=node({stack}) 
MATCH (stack)-[:Item]-(item)-[:Representation]-(representation)
RETURN representation
```

(`representation` in this query is the equivalent of `node` I just didn't have enough space in the above diagram to keep writing representation).

Now as expected this query only returns a flat list of representations related to all `item` nodes. e.g.

```
[ representation, representation, representation.... ]
```

What I really want is a query to return a nested structure of `items` with their related `representation`s e.g.

```
[ 
    [ item, representations ],
    [ item, representations ],
    [ item, representations ] 
]
```

The exact structure of the `return` is not important. It's just so that I can easily map an `item` to it's `representations` without sending a query for each `item`s `representations`.

This might seem like a trivial question but after looking through the Cypher cheat sheet and watching videos and googling Cypher tutorials. I haven't yet found a simple set of explanations on how to use Cypher to perform such a query (or most queries actually).

(On a side note if anyone also knows of a "Cypher for dummies" tutorial I would much appreciate it.)

Comment: `return item, representations`, no?

Comment: @JamesR I have no clue, I never understood the purpose of the `,` I figured it meant return a flat list of `items` and a flat list of `representations`. I will try it :)

Comment: @JamesR Just tried it and it does indeed return a flat list of `items` and `representations`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use [aggregation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-aggregation.html).

```
RETURN item, collect(representation) as representations
```

Aggregation works without `group by` like this.

If you use at least one aggregation function (`count`, `collect`, `avg`, `min`, `max` etc.) in your `return` clause, then all *non-aggregated* columns are treated as grouping key.

In SQL you would write something like:

```
SELECT item, collect(representation) as representations
FROM ...
GROUP BY item
```

Which is just a repetitive declaration.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick thanks. Is it possible for you  to describe why this works when `RETURN item, representation` returns a flat list ? it seems a bit counterintuitive to understand how `collect()` is working.

Comment: Not to be unappreciative of your answer as it clearly works. However I think it would be useful for the community, if you could provide a bit more explanation in your answer as to whats going on and why this works.